# aws ec2 public ip from vpc timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to configure aws vpc/subnet so that the public ip4 addresses are reachable from within the VPC?

At the moment, the ec2 machine's ip4 addresses are reachable from the internet, but timeout when connecting from within the same machine or from another machine on the same subnet.

Comment: Reachable from where? Public or private subnets?

Comment: The machine is obviously in a public subnet since you can connect to it from the Internet.
Also, the routing is obviously OK.
Do you allow outbound connections to the Internet from the machines in your public subnet? (Security Groups, ACLs)

Answer (score 0):

Quite embarrasing. But maybe this will help someone in the future.

We had a security group assigned to the instances which only allowed specific ips to access http ports. The sec groups also apply to instances within the same subnet, so an access rule from instances with the same security group was added which resolved the problem. Alternatively you can also allow access by private ip, for instance.

So if it ever happens that you need to access localhost via the public ip, access must be allowed by the active security group.

Comment: Glad you got it solved! You should always communicate within the VPC via private IP addresses. If a public IP address is used, the traffic goes "out" of the VPC, then back in again (with a 1c/GB charge). Also FYI, security groups can refer to each other so Instance A with Security Group A can access Instance B with Security Group B by adding an Inbound rule in Security Group B that permits access from Security Group A (without the need to refer to specific IP addresses).

Comment: I 100% agree with you. Yet sometimes the client "knows best".